# fast find lines in zipfile without hitting memory

Tags: python

What is the fastest way to search for lines in zipFile containing .txt?

The size of zipfile is around 100mb and after extraction is around 700mb so I can't extract and read the text file in memory.

Is there any possibility where I can read the zipfile in memory (100 mb) and do search?

currently I do.

```
with ZipFile(zip_file) as myzip:
    with myzip.open(myzip.namelist()[0]) as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            if line.startswith("interesting words"):
                print(line)
```

which takes around 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ZipFile` code you have is lazy in reading and decompressing your data. It reads 4 Kb of compressed data at a time, decompresses it into memory and then scans it for newlines as you iterate on the file object.

If you want to read the whole text of the file at once, use something like this:

```
with ZipFile(zip_file) as myzip:
    with myzip.open(myzip.namelist()[0]) as myfile:
        text = myfile.read() # reads the whole file into a single string
    for line in text.splitlines(): # you might be able to use regex on text instead of a loop
        if line.startswith("interesting words"):
            print(line)
```

I have no idea if this will be any faster than your current code. If it's not, you may want to profile your code to make sure the decompression is the part that's slowing it down (rather than something else). As I commented in the code, you might find that using a regular expression search on the `text` string is better than splitting it up into lines and iterating over them searching each one individually.

Comment: i guess [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) may give some speed-up, but not sure

Comment: text = myfile.read() without hitting memory? Its 700mb file insize zip. I can only read upto 100 mb that is size of zipfile not the uncompressed text. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Sure, that uses a lot of memory, but even with Python's overheads, a 700 MB string is probably not more than your computer can handle. This code tries to trade memory usage for speed (though I don't really know how much speed benefit you'll see in reality). Your existing code is about as good as it gets if you really do need to minimize memory usage while still having simple code.